# Sumar unos minutos al obtenido actualmente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Algo debo estar haciendo mal porque cuando sumo 5 minutos al tiempo que acabo de obtener sale un resultado que no está en minutos.

Tengo la siguiente función en `javascript` y `jquery` que estoy ejecutando con `tampermonkey`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Time Session Intranet
// @namespace   nnn
// @version     1.0
// @description nnn
// @author      nnn
// @match       nnn/*
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery;

$(function() {

    $("#usuario").append(contador());

});

function contador() {

    var fecha = new Date();
    var sumarsesion = 5;

    return fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha.setMinutes(fecha.getMinutes() + sumarsesion);

}
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente

> 40:1533732320697

El primero tiempo está bien obtenido, es decir, si ponemos que la página la cargo a las 14:40, devuelve 40 como primer valor correctamente, pero ¿luego no tendría que devolver 45?

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo cambia la función contador por:

```
function contador() {
    var fecha = new Date();
    var sumarsesion = 5;
    return fecha.getMinutes() + ":" + (fecha.setMinutes(fecha.getMinutes() + sumarsesion) && fecha.getMinutes());
}
```

o su equivalente

```
function contador() {
    var fecha = new Date();
    var sumarsesion = 5;
    var minutes = fecha.getMinutes();

    fecha.setMinutes(minutes + sumarsesion);
    return  minutes + ":" + fecha.getMinutes();
}
```

Tu error está en que `fecha.setMinutes()` devuelve el timestamp del objeto `fecha`, no devuelve los minutos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa, es que la función setMinutes te devuelve ese valor, que es **un número representando los milisegundos de diferencia entre tu objeto Date y el primero de enero de 1970**. Esto según la [Documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setminutes.asp)

Si haces algo como:

```
fecha = new Date();
```

Luego:

```
fecha.setMinutes(fecha.getMinutes() + 5);
```

Habrás sumado correctamente 5 minutos a tu fecha.

Lo que debes hacer después, es mostrarla como corresponde usando los métodos necesarios, si quieres mostrar los minutos, debes usar nuevamente:

```
fecha.getMinutes();
```

Pero en tu código intentabas concatenar directamente el resultado de setMinutes, que es lo que te comenté arriba.